# Send PHP Variable with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wrote a PHP application that makes an AJAX call (XMLHttpRequest) and is called every 5 seconds. The page called makes a database query. However, I need a variable from the main page and am unable to find a solution to attach it to the Ajax call.

Using $_GET seems a bit too insecure to me. Is there another way here?

This is my first expierence with ajax so please dont be to hard with me :)

Here is my Ajax Call

```
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
    loadText() }, 5000);

    function loadText(){
    
        //XHR Objekt
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // OPEN
        xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/table_view.php?role=<?php echo $role.'&name='.$_SESSION['name'].'&org='.$_SESSION['org'];?>', true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if(this.status == 200){

                document.getElementById('table_view_div').innerHTML = this.responseText;            }
       
                })


            if(this.status == 404){
                document.getElementById('apps').innerHTML = 'ERROR';
            }
        }

        xhr.send();

        // console.log(xhr);
    }
```

Ill hope i provided enough Information

WIsh u all a great weekend

Comment: You can just change GET to POST in the ajax call and then read it using $_POST. See here for an example of the difference in code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send What exactly is your security concern with doing it this way?

Comment: Also, it doesn't really make sense to use $_SESSION variables in the ajax request. you can just read those server side (which is what you should be doing anyway as the user could easily change that data before submitting the request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need sending session variables at all: those are already known to the called page, because it can share the session information of the calling page.

```
// OPEN
xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/table_view.php?role=<?= $role ?>'
```

is enough, provided that "table_view.php" issues a `session_start()` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code; It's here:

(Note: \' means that the character ' doesn't closing the string.)

```
const myInterval = setInterval(function(){loadText();}, 5000);

function loadText(){
  //XHR Objekt
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // OPEN
  xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/table_view.php?role=<?php echo $role.\'&name=\'.$_SESSION[\'name\'].\'&org=\'.$_SESSION[\'org\']; ?>', true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(this.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('table_view_div').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    if(this.status == 404){
      document.getElementById('apps').innerHTML = 'ERROR';
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work: the "<?php" tag starts a PHP code section, in which `echo $role.\'&name=...` is a syntax error.